# Configuring cross connects in a data center

Tags: networking

We recently got a machine set up in a data center. Our next step was to connect to a data provider using a cross connect. We filled a form and received a list of IPs labeled Gateway, Network Interface etc and were informed that the cross connects were successful. We are software engineers and currently we do not know how to set up this cross connect. We are connecting to our main server using a remote desktop software and would like to cross connect the data provider for which a physical cross connect has been setup.

Thanks,

Aziz

Comment: You should hire a consultant to work this out for you.

Comment: Thanks Spaceman. Unfortunately, this had not been taken into account while allocating project budget at the start of the project..so I'm afraid thats not a real possibility :(

Comment: Wow. That totally and utterly sucks. Time to have a word with the project manager.

Answer (score 1):

Start with referring to [What does "cross connect" means in Datacenters?](https://serverfault.com/q/187829/3139)

I assume your network interface is the address that you should assign the interface attached to the cross connect wire. Your gateway is the router that is attached to the other end of that wire and feeds into the rest of the network that comes from the cross connect.

Depending on the network setup, you may want to make that a default gateway address or involve some sort of fancier routing.